# плохая работа arch linux

Tags: linux, archlinux

Всем привет, прошу вас помочь с решение проблемы arch linux. Система установленна на ноутбуке, при включении бывает такая ситуация(начинает моргать капслок, система уходит в черный экран и никаких признаков жизни не подает) Так же при работе бывает что система перестает как либо реагировать на комманды (я точно уверен что в этот момент не запущенны программы способные загрузить оперативку или проц, собственно кроме самой системы). Всем хорошего времени

Я пробовал полностью переустанавливать всю систему, использовать проприетарные драва и опен соурс, а так же менял окружения системы. Полностью обновлял. Реакции ноль. у меня ноутбук huawei matebook 14d

Comment: проплиетарные, признпков, драва, комманды. если ессть время, пжалуйста, исправте опечатки

Comment: Мне кажется что проблемы железа у вас а не оси. Попробуйте поставить какую нибудь другую систему и проверить сохранились ли проблемы

Comment: А что вы ждали от китайцев?

Comment: вы бы поточнее определили свою модель ноутбука, в интернете находятся довольно разные как по году выпуска так и по начинке

Comment: @Mpmp В других дистрибутивах такой проблемы нет

Comment: @Zt.
huawei matebook d 14 NBLK-WAX9X

Comment: я так понимаю это система 2020 года на ядре Ryzen 5 3500U ? если да, то попробуйте вариант описанный для данной модели - [Freeze during intensive tasks](https://github.com/All3xJ/linux-on-huawei-matebook-d-14-amd#freeze-during-intensive-tasks)